# how do we push a checkbox to an array while checkbox is by default checked in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

the checkbox by default checked if this checkbox is by default checked then it should be automatically pushed into addtess_type array.
https://react-jkrrcb.stackblitz.io demo

```
handleInputChangeDom = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    var value = target.value;
    const Address_type = this.state.Address_type;
    
    if (event.target.checked) {
      Address_type.push(event.target.value);
    } else {
      let index = Address_type.indexOf(event.target.value);
      Address_type.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.setState({
      Address_type: Address_type,

    });
  };
```

Comment: Please add more code snippets. It's hard to check which array of yours have default check. If it is possible than please add whole component or make working demo so we can take better look. thanks

Comment: i have 2 checkboxes. and one of them is checked by default.  so if the checkbox is checked by default then it should be automatically pushed to an array.

Comment: You mentioned the checkbox is by default checked and you want to push it to an array, then what is `handleInputChangeDom` method is for? This looks like an event listener, how is it relevant to what you are asking for?

Comment: bro, that is an event I am using to push the checkboxes to an adress_type array. but this is working well for unchecked checkboxes but if the checkbox is by default checked this is not working.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela please check i have add some code and a live project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to maintain a `state` of all the checked items.
One advice would be to use `Set` instead of an array. It will make life so much more easier for you.

```js
const handleInputChangeDom = (event) => {
    const newSet = new Set(this.state.Address_type); // create a clone, don't update current state
    if(event.target.checked) {
      newSet.add(event.target.value);
    } else {
      newSet.delete(event.target.value);
    }
    this.setState({ Address_type: newSet });
}
```

One suggestion - please try to use `camelCase` with `React`, that is suggested.

Comment: this is working fine. but there is still main problem is untouched. there another checkbox which is checked. this checkedbox should be already pushed into array. that is the main problem

Comment: Sorry @lunatic, that is more of a problem which how you are initialising your state. That part should be taken care of by your state initialisation. When you initialise your state, it should already be a part of your `this.state.Address_type`. You haven't uploaded much of your code, so cannot comment more, but if you add the already selected entries to your constructor or wherever you are initialising your state, it would work well for sure.

Comment: sir, I have mentioned the link above you should check once where the STREET checkbox is checked by default and another one is not checked by default.

my problem is when the STREET checkbox is checked by default then I want its value should be presented already into an array. hope you got my problem if not let me know I will explain it again because I am stuck there very badly.

Comment: jaiBhatt, can you help me ?

Comment: <Button
              className="btn btn-success greenbtn biggreenbtn mt-2"
              onClick={() => {
                if (product.id === product.id) {
                  handleAddToCart(product.id, count  );  
                  setCount(preCount => preCount + 1);
                } else {
                  setCount(count);
                }
              }}
            >
              Add To Cart
            </Button>
....................this is my button when I press this button again, the counter should be start from 1 in react using hook.  how plz ?

Comment: Can you please host the code in some codepen and send over the link? It's getting difficult to understand the code.